# How to use windows identity federation to validate a saml token in a c# class library?

Tags: c#, windows, token, saml

I’m trying to use the windows identity federation framework to validate a saml token in a c# class library.

However, every article I read about this library suggests that the classes within it, like the securitytokenhandler, have their fields set within the web.config file. These fields contain things like the acceptable token issuers and audience that are needed for validation. In a c# class library, not an mvc project, that doesn’t exist.

Does anyone know how to configure the fields of windows identity federation classes in a classlibrary? And if it can’t be done without a web.config, does anyone know how to manually validate a saml token?

I tried creating a web.config within class library but it didn’t load.